# The constructor InputStreamReader(File) is undefined

Tags: java, java-7, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, inputstreamreader

```
import java.io.*;

public class Streams {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File homedir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        File is = new File(homedir, "java/in.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        int value = 0;
        while ((value=br.read())!=-1) {
            char c = (char) value;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

while compiling the above program i am getting error like this

> ERROR in Streams.java (at line 7) BufferedReader br = new
>   BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
>                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> The constructor InputStreamReader(File) is undefined
>
> ---

kindly help me out this problem i am using java `1.7.0_51` version, `OS linux Deepin`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You use Java 7?

Then:

```
Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(System.getProperty("home.dir")
    .resolve("java/in.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You use Java 7? Drop `File` entirely. See [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), `Paths`, `FileSystems`, etc etc.

(edit: and use the try-with-resources statement; see @JonSkeet's answer for more details)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's quite right. Look at the [documentation for `InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and you won't find a constructor taking a `File` parameter.

Instead, you should construct a `FileInputStream` to read from the file, and pass *that* to the constructor of the `InputStreamReader`. You should also specify the encoding you want to use, otherwise it'll use the platform default encoding.

Also note:

- You should use a try-with-resources statement to close the resource automatically
- I wouldn't name a `File` variable `is` - that sounds more like you'd expect it to be an `InputStream`.

So for example:

```
File file = new File(homedir, "java/in.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    int value = 0;
    while ((value = br.read()) != -1) {
        char c = (char) value;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

(Or use the `Files` API as per fge's answer.)

Comment: @Selva: "I am getting error" doesn't tell us anything about *what* the error is. If it's because the compiler can't find `StandardCharsets`, that's because you need an import for it (e.g. `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;`.)

Comment: @JohnSkeet gelp me to find sollution

Comment: @Selva: How can I help you to find a solution when you won't say what the error is?

Comment: @JohnSkeet while import 'java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;' this package it tells: The import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets cannot be resolved

Comment: sir no sir i will compile my program using 'javac -source 5 filename.java' only

Comment: @Selva: Why are you specifying -source 5?

Comment: because it will defaultly take jdk 1.4, so sorry to say i will specify 'javac -source 7 filename.java' sir.......

Comment: @Selva: Why have you got it set up to default to JDK 1.4 source? I don't even know *how* you'd set it up that way... and certainly I can't see any reason you'd *want* it set up that way. A stock install of JDK 7 will default to a source level of 7.

Comment: sir no if i compile using this way only i can use the jdk 7 other wise it will use jdk 4 only. the best example is for each loop it will works after 5 version only if i compile file normally it wont work in my system for for-each loop

Comment: @Selva: Well I don't know how you've set it up that way. That's very odd indeed. (Note that it's not actually using the JDK 1.4; it's just compiling with the language features from Java 1.4.)

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(is)));`
and it should work.

Comment: And you still got the same exception ?

Comment: while compiling your way i am getting FileNotFound  and IOexception sir

Comment: thats because you are setting wrong path. That is off the topic.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` says otherwise and I trust it.